# Definition of cost function and likelihood: how one appears from the other

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimation, expected-value, likelihood, loss-functions

I was reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.02911) and the book "Introduction to Quantum State Estimation" by Yong Siah Teo and I am facing some issues trying to understand how the definition of the cost function given in these two references can match each other and how the likelihood function can rise from this definition.

The paper reads:

[image]

And the books says:

[image]

Although they seem the same, there are some differences that I cannot understand how to connect one with the other. I mean, the equation $(2)$ seems to be the same one as the $1.2.1$ from the book, except for the summation symbol when taking defining the average cost function. This summation symbol is defined later in the book as:

[image]

My issues are simply that:

1. I cannot see how to connect these two definitions. This summation symbol that is defining *"a conditional average over all possible measurement data"* does not seem to enter in any way in the definition of the paper, which seems more plausible since minimizing a cost function is just taking the average *"over all possible true configurations"* which is the integral the author on the paper stated.
2. why the likelihood function appears in the average?
3. How to connect these two definitions considering this summation (average) with the likelihood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the interest in my book! I am the author, so let me try to give you a simple answer to your questions.

In the paper, the cost function is defined with respect to a single measurement dataset ($\mathbb{D}$ with my notation, and D with theirs). This is often the cost function one is interested in since one is usually interested in the problem defined by this particular dataset. For the case of the book, the purpose was to connect ideas of various types of state estimators with the cost function, and so I considered the additional averaging over $\mathbb{D}$. This explains the additional data average sum, which involves the likelihood function for a correct statistical average over datasets.

In short, these are two different cost functions, and the one considered in the book is by no means the only legitimate one. It is only an option to introduce estimators. The choice of which cost function to use really depends on your objective.

Comment: Hello! Your book is excellent, I am using it as one of my main references for learning and understanding the subject. Thanks for your answer. It does make sense.